# What species is this burrow-digging insect?

Tags: species-identification, entomology, hymenoptera

These are frames from a recent recording:

[image: 1]
[image: 2]
[image: 3]
[image: 4]

---

### Location

Urban area in Central Europe.

### Abiotic factors at the time of recording

- Temperature = 27°
- Humidity = 51%
- Wind = 16 km/h

### Description

- Approximate size = <strike>6 cm</strike> 4-5 cm
- Elongated shape
- Distinctive orange-ish abdominal segment near the end of the abdomen
- 6 legs
- One pair of wings (I think it's very possible that it has two pairs of wings, though, hard to see on the video or pictures)

### Observed behavior

The insect seemed to be digging burrows in one of my pots (so far there are 3 holes in one pot and I also saw another burrow in a second pot). Every time I've seen it, it was alone so I assume it's not a social species.

### Internet search

I ran these images through google search images and the results were (in order):

- hymenopteran
- insect
- pest
- carpenter ant

I think the closest match was the first picture but I wasn't able to get a specific species so I would appreciate any insight from experts on the matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is clearly a type of wasp.  Some digging leads me to think it could be something in the genus *[Ammophila](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammophila_(wasp))* (a type of "thread-waisted wasp") for example *[Ammophila sabulosa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ammophila_sabulosa)*:

[image: Ammophila sabulosa — by: John Vallender — from: bwars.com —]

However, 6 cm is **huge** for a wasp and twice the size of *Ammophila sabulosa* — are you sure about that length?

Comment: The page you linked states 15 to 25mm. https://www.google.com/search?q=Ammophila+sabulosa+ruler&tbm=isch&ved=2ahUKEwiTpMiW562BAxWruCcCHR28BLgQ2-cCegQIABAA&oq=Ammophila+sabulosa+ruler&gs_lcp=CgNpbWcQAzoECCMQJzoHCAAQGBCABDoECAAQHlCxDFjQIGDRImgCcAB4AIABdIgB6wWSAQM4LjGYAQCgAQGqAQtnd3Mtd2l6LWltZ8ABAQ&sclient=img&ei=n-0EZdPYCqvxnsEPnfiSwAs&bih=580&biw=1242#imgrc=mVGVyPlWqFlclM